# Inheritance rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, model

I'm looking for an inheritance case for ruby on rails. I have a structure: `User` => `Listworker` => `Pro` so that `Listworker` has `user_id` and `Pro` has `listworker_id`, and I have ruby code like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attrib : surname, name
end

class Listworker < ActiveRecord::Base
  attrib : score
end

class Pro < ActiveRecord::Base
  attrib : website
end
```

I want to do something such as:

- `Listworker.surname` instead of `Listworker.user.surname`
- `Pro.surname` instead of `Pro.listworker.user.surname`

STI isn't a solution because I have too much things to store in `Listworker` and `Pro`.

Answer (score 0):

You can [delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) the method to `user` object:

```
class ListWorker < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :surname, to: :user
end

class Pro < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list_worker
  delegate :surname, to: :list_worker
end
```

and you will be able to call it `:surname` on ListWorker or Pro instance:

```
ListWorker.find(123).surname 
Pro.first.surname
```

Also, the structure you provided *is not an inheritance*, but *associations*.

- Pro belongs_to ListWorker
- ListWorker belongs_to User
- Pro has_one User through ListWorker

Comment: Hi, that's a part of the answer but I'll not be able to do Pro.first.surname.

Moreover, it required each time to call the database even if I call 100 users. I want to be able to load User attribute and Listworker attribute at the same time. Same for User function.

My code doesn't look like inheritance but I want to such as Pro < Listworker < User

Comment: @Thounder, ok, I'll add part about Pro to answer, but to keep database queries count at minimum, you should use [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) instead of trying to put everything into every model.